Ptolemy, what Greek letters did he use to represent base pos numbers?
I recall reading that Ptolemy in the Greek version of Almagast, used the Greek alphabet to represent his table of chords in Base 60 using Base 10. Does anyone know where I can find this version and what Base 10 digit maps to each Greek letter?
I’m guessing he used a mapping from 1 to 9 over the first nine Greek letters in alphabetical order. All I can find is Almagast using Hindu/Arabic numerals.
The following is a guess:
Α α 1   Alpha   a
Β β 2   Beta    b
Γ γ 3   Gamma   g
Δ δ 4   Delta   d
Ε ε 5   Epsilon e
(Ϝ ϝ / Ϛ ϛ) 6   Digamma (later Stigma)  w / st
Ζ ζ 7   Zeta    z
Η η 8   Eta
I also see Cyrillic numerals reflect above before Slavs changed to Arabic numerals in late 1700. This would also reflect Slavic adoption of Greek alphabet. Wikipedia has an article that shows the above pattern 1-9. I also read that zero is represented by o or omicron.

Welcome to HSM Stack Exchange.  Cf. this Wikipedia article

Interesting but it doesn’t show what Ptolemy used

Wikipedia also has Ptolemy's table of chords from Almagest in the original notation with the conversion table of Arabic into Attic numerals. The first nine digits did follow the first nine letters with the archaic digamma/stigma included.

("What Greek letters did Ptolemy use [for numbers]?")
The statement about Ptolemy's numerical usages in his chord-table and elsewhere (as recalled by the questioner) looks as if it came from a  highly abbreviated source -- so it can perhaps not be expected to be fully accurate.
The most relevant sources seem to be (a) the original Greek, in Heiberg's critical edition of 1898 (available at https://archive.org/details/pt1claudiiptolemaei01ptoluoft ), (b) the well-received 1984 English translation ("Ptolemy's Almagest, translated and annotated by G J Toomer", 1984, ISBN 0 7156 1388 2), and (c) the translator's commentary.
Starting with (c), Toomer (1984: p.6-7)  wrote that Ptolemy used the sexagesimal system only for fractions (and then not always).  For the integer parts of composite numbers he retained the Greek alphabetic notation. This  was not exactly base-10 even though it mainly followed powers of 10, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals . An example given by Toomer shows how a number made up of 373 (integer parts or degrees), 10 (sixtieths or minutes), 0 (seconds), and 58 (thirds) was written by Ptolemy:--

The Greek here for the '373' and '10' shows by example how the system was not exactly base-10. (The wikipedia article at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords#The_numeral_system_and_the_appearance_of_the_untranslated_table , although useful, is not completely accurate.)
'Not exactly base-10' means the system was not actually positional. There was a set of letters for units (specifically: alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon, sigma, zeta, eta, theta, for 1-9), and another set for multiples of 10 upwards (starting: iota, kappa, lambda, mu, nu for 10-50). Thus the symbol for 10 could be used alone for 10 itself, it did not need a positional indicator, it could not be confused with 1. The principle was aggregative more than positional.
About the fractions (not always sexagesimal), Toomer wrote that "Except where it is necessary to be precise, Ptolemy prefers the traditional Greek fractional system to the sexagesimal."  The Greek system preferred to aggregate using component fractions  with small and preferably unit numerators: so 3/4 was often written 1/2 1/4 (diagonal strokes used here only because of the digital coding); there were special signs for '2/3' and some of the other fractions.
As for the chord table (Almagest, Book 1, sec.11), here are images of an extract of the English translation at p.57 in the translation (b) (this effectively uses double columns, the left half matching one page in the Greek while the right half matches another). Also corresponding extracts of the Greek in (a) (respectively matching the left and right halves of the translated table-extract) -- to allow their comparison.
1  Starting extract of Toomer's translated numerical chord table from Ptolemy's Almagest:

2  Greek source for the left half of the foregoing translation:

3  Greek source for the right half of the foregoing translation:


This very helpful! So using the 373 example it appears for each digit the Greek letter used by Ptolemy corresponds to both the positional value and the base exponent multiplied together, so nothing shown is implicit to which number base is chosen for the positional number system used like Arabic/Hindu. It appears a horizontal bar is used over the letter to show it’s a number and for zero there is no bar over omicron which is only used alone. I see a comma is used in front of letter to multiply by 10^4. Does two commas multiply by 10^8?

@notaorb : taking the '373' example, (tau omicron gamma), the tau means 300, the omicron means 70 and the gamma means 3. There's no multiplication to do, no exponent to consider, and no positional dependence of the symbol values, it is just aggregative, thus 300+70+3. There are unlikely to be commas in the original, and there's nothing to indicate coded instructions to multiply.
